# Can i skip the first activity?

Tags: android, android-activity

my code is

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        try {
            Log.d("response", "starting city connection");
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(
                    "http://10.0.2.2/wic3/wic2/mobile/verifyUser");

            ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            sessionResponse = SignUpActivity.httpclient.execute(httppost,
                    responseHandler);
            Log.d("session response", "" + sessionResponse);

            if (sessionResponse.equals("true")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(SignUpActivity.this,
                        FeedListViewActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("error", "Error in http connection" + e.toString());
        }
```

.............

my question is can i skip the 1st activity(or screen) and directly load some other screen depending on any condition???my intention was to load the home page (skip the login page) if a session already exists....in my case the sessionResponse is true but i still get the login page

Comment: Have you tried it? It should work fine.

Comment: 1st activity means which? What you want to implement exactly?

Comment: yeah i tried it.....it still gives me the 1st screen(login page)

Comment: @Paresh....this activity actually loads a login screen...but if a session already exists(if sessionResponse.equals("true")) then i want it to load feed page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of the following code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(SignUpActivity.this,FeedListViewActivity.class);  
startActivity(intent);
```

Simply put `setContentView()`. `setContentView()` is the method that displays the screen in android to the User Interface. If you dont call this method then nothing will be displayed. You will see only a blank screen. Modify your above code as follows

```
if (sessionResponse.equals("true")) 
     setContentView(R.layout.screen1);
else  
     setContentView(R.layout.screen2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can Don't set View using setContentView and check the condition and nevigate to the desired activity and finish your first activity. But if your Condition is false you have to handle that too otherwise nothing will be displayed.

Comment: u mean write this intent before setContentView() call??...yeah i did that